# ¿Cómo puedo ordenar los resultados de un SELECT?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo un problema con una consulta en Base de datos,

```
SELECT  
        CantAceptable,
        CantBajo,
        CantModerado,
        CantAlto,
        CantMuyAlto FROM TABLA
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es de acuerdo a los valores que vengan en la consulta, ordene de mayor a menor los datos y los campos de la tabla es decir, debería de quedar así:

- 1 Fila:  CantMuyAlto, CantAceptable, CantBajo, CantModerado,
  CantAlto
- 2 Fila:  CantAceptable, CantMuyAlto, CantBajo,
     CantModerado, CantAlto
- 3 Fila:  CantAlto,  CantModerado,
        CantMuyAlto, CantAceptable, CantBajo
- 4 Fila:  CantAceptable,
        CantModerado, CantBajo, CantAlto, CantMuyAlto

En pocas palabras ordenar de mayor a menor la posición de la columna y su respectivo valor **DESC**

Comment: Puedes mostrar el resultado que quieres?

Comment: Ahi esta en el detalle, necesito que ordene las filas y las columnas

Comment: Podría [edit] tu pregunta e incluir el resultado esperado. Podrías usar por ejemplo Excel y añadirlo como imagen. Sería bueno que revises el [tour].

Comment: El tema es que tu detalle no se entiende....mejor poner el resultado deseado tal como pusiste el resultado actual

Comment: El resultado esperado esta en la lista de viñetas practicamente quiere regresar una consulta donde los campos se ordenen por fila de mayor a menor, el unico inconveniente que veo es que los campos no se pueden ordenar y mesclar con otro campo para el orden horizontal por lo que por ejemplo CantAceptable en el set de resultados no puede traer el valor de CantAlto, CantBajo, etc... que es parte de lo que el OP busca

Comment: Estar planteando mal la estructura de tu table entonces, ya que no puedes alterar la pocision de las columnas por cada fila en un servidor de Base de datos, tal vez, desde el lenguaje de Programacion puedas o quizas con SP pero no creo que con una simple consulta como la que haces, puedas reordenar las columnas a tu gusto porque simplemente, no se podria ya que eso la coordenada correspondiente al valor no coincidia con la columna

Answer (score 2):

Lo cierto es que una sola consulta no puede hacerlo, no me imagino para que podrias quererlo asi, pero la unica solucion que se me ocurre es un Union para cada una de las convinaciones de columnas con el where correspondiente, lo que quedaria algo asi:

```
SELECT  CantAceptable, CantBajo, CantModerado, CantAlto, CantMuyAlto FROM TABLA WHERE CantAceptable > CantBajo and  CantBajo > CantModerado and CantModerado > CantAlto and CantAlto > CantMuyAlto
UNION
SELECT  CantBajo, CantAceptable, CantModerado, CantAlto, CantMuyAlto FROM TABLA WHERE CantBajo > CantAceptable and  CantAceptable > CantModerado and CantModerado > CantAlto and CantAlto > CantMuyAlto
UNION
SELECT ..... ETC
```

Pero esta solucion costaria demaciados UNION ademas de ser desoptimizada e inpractica.

Supongo que el concepto en el cual lo quieres aplicar está mal, seria mas correcto que precentes el problema al que te enfrentas (y quieres aplicar esta solucion) y quizas brindemos alternativas mas viables.